# How do i remove the index on a laravel collection for reading as an object only?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, orm, builder

What i have:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1299 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1308 ▼
      +"id_itemnfe": 1
      +"fk_nfe": 1
      +"nitemped": "1"...
```

So i have to ready as:
`$data[0]->id_itemnfe;`
or use foreach.

I was a Codeigniter user, what there was a `row() method` where i could print as `$data->id_itemnfe` directly.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you show your laravel query?

Comment: I just found the answer at laravel documentation. The equivalent method is called "first()" in Laravel. Thanks anyway!! Shall i exclude the question? What am i suposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative for Codeigniter `row() method` in laravel is `first() method`, it will return the first row and you can access your variables directly e.g. `$data->id_itemnfe`

**Syntax:**

```
Model::where('fieldname',$value)->first();
```

**Example:**

```
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first();
```